# How to make tableview reload correct data?

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

I am trying to build an app that decodes a JSON with data about cryptocurrencies. After I fetch the data I calculate the daily turnover ratio of each coin and depending on the percentage I put the coin in one out of four lists.

If I change the selectedList property in the viewModel and run the app the tableView loads the appropriate list. But when I change the value of selectedList in runtime nothing happens. The output of the print statement in the selectedList -> didSet changes but the output of the print statement inside the didLoadCoins method in the view that reloads the tableview remains the same as it was when the app started.

What am I doing wrong?

**Viewcontroller**

```
class TVMainViewController: UIViewController, TVMainViewControllerViewButtonDelegate {
    
    private let mainView = TVMainViewControllerView()
    private let viewModel = TVMainViewControllerViewModel()
    
    
    
    //MARK: - Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        mainView.delegate = self
        viewModel.delegate = mainView
        setupUI()
        
        
    }
    
    func didTapSelectRangeButton() {
        let destinationVC = TVSelectRangeViewController()
        destinationVC.modalPresentationStyle = .pageSheet
        destinationVC.sheetPresentationController?.detents = [.medium()]
        destinationVC.sheetPresentationController?.prefersGrabberVisible = true
        
        destinationVC.viewModel = viewModel
        
        present(destinationVC, animated: true)
    }
    
    //MARK: - UI Setup
    private func setupUI() {
        ...
    }
```

**view**

```
protocol TVMainViewControllerViewButtonDelegate {
    func didTapSelectRangeButton()    
}


final class TVMainViewControllerView: UIView, TVMainViewControllerViewModelDelegate {
    
    //MARK: - Variables
    private var viewModel = TVMainViewControllerViewModel()
    var delegate: TVMainViewControllerViewButtonDelegate?
    
    //MARK: - Initializers
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        viewModel.delegate = self
        setupTableView()
        setupUI()
        Task {
            await viewModel.decodeData {
                self.viewModel.delegate?.didLoadCoins()
            }

        }
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
    //MARK: - Functions
    private func setupTableView() {
        tableView.register(VTMainTableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: Constants.mainTableViewCell)
        tableView.dataSource = viewModel
    }
    
    func didLoadCoins() {
        print(viewModel.selectedList)
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    @objc func selectRange() {
        delegate?.didTapSelectRangeButton()
    }
    
    //MARK: - UI Setup
    private func setupUI() {
       ...
    }
}
```

**viewModel**

```
import UIKit

/// Communicate with the View to notify it that the data are loaded
protocol TVMainViewControllerViewModelDelegate {
    func didLoadCoins()
}

class TVMainViewControllerViewModel: NSObject {
    
    //MARK: - Variables
    private let networkManager = NetworkManager()
    //    private let baseURL = "https://api.coinlore.net/api/tickers/?start=0&limit=10"
    
    private var coinList = [Cryptocurrency]()
    private var liquidityAbove30List = [CryptoLiquidityModel]()
    private var liquidityAbove20List = [CryptoLiquidityModel]()
    private var liquidityAbove10List = [CryptoLiquidityModel]()
    private var liquidityBelow10List = [CryptoLiquidityModel]()
    private var coinLiquidityList = [CryptoLiquidityModel]()
    var delegate: TVMainViewControllerViewModelDelegate?
    
    var selectedList: Int = 0  {
        didSet {
            print(selectedList)
            delegate?.didLoadCoins()
        }
    }
    
    
    //MARK: - Functions
    
    /// Run networking task and fetch data. It makes 5 network call each of which fetches 100 coins
    func decodeData(completion: @escaping () -> Void) async {
        coinList = []
        var page = 0
        
        while page < 200 {
            let baseURL = "https://api.coinlore.net/api/tickers/?start=\(page)&limit=100"
            
            networkManager.execute(url: baseURL) { result in
                switch result {
                case.success(let decodedData):
                    for coin in decodedData.data {
                        self.coinList.append(coin)
                        self.calculateDailyTurnoverRatio(coin: coin)
                        
                        self.delegate?.didLoadCoins()
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            page += 100
            
        } //endwhile
        
        completion()
    }
    
    
    /// Calculate liquidity by dividing daily volume/market cap
    /// Creates 4 lists. Each list contains the coins that have the given turnover ration
    func calculateDailyTurnoverRatio(coin: Cryptocurrency) {
        coinLiquidityList = []
        
        
        let coinLiquidity24 = (coin.volume24 / Double(coin.market_cap_usd)!)*100
        let newCoin = CryptoLiquidityModel(cryptocurrency: coin, liquidity24: coinLiquidity24)
        
        switch coinLiquidity24 {
        case 30 ... 100:
            liquidityAbove30List.append(newCoin)
        case 20 ... 29:
            liquidityAbove20List.append(newCoin)
        case 10 ... 19:
            liquidityAbove10List.append(newCoin)
        default:
            liquidityBelow10List.append(newCoin)
        }
        
    }
    
    
}


extension TVMainViewControllerViewModel: UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        switch selectedList {
        case 0:
            return liquidityBelow10List.count
        case 1:
            return liquidityAbove10List.count
        case 2:
            return liquidityAbove20List.count
        case 3:
            return liquidityAbove30List.count
        default:
            return liquidityBelow10List.count        }    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constants.mainTableViewCell, for: indexPath) as! VTMainTableViewCell
        
        switch selectedList {
        case 0:
            let coin = liquidityBelow10List[indexPath.row]
            cell.set(coinSymbol: coin.cryptocurrency.name,
                     coinPrice: coin.cryptocurrency.price_usd,
                     change24: coin.cryptocurrency.percent_change_24h,
                     liquidity24: String(format: "%.2f", coin.liquidity24))
        case 1:
            let coin = liquidityAbove10List[indexPath.row]
            cell.set(coinSymbol: coin.cryptocurrency.name,
                     coinPrice: coin.cryptocurrency.price_usd,
                     change24: coin.cryptocurrency.percent_change_24h,
                     liquidity24: String(format: "%.2f", coin.liquidity24))
            
        case 2:
            let coin = liquidityAbove20List[indexPath.row]
            cell.set(coinSymbol: coin.cryptocurrency.name,
                     coinPrice: coin.cryptocurrency.price_usd,
                     change24: coin.cryptocurrency.percent_change_24h,
                     liquidity24: String(format: "%.2f", coin.liquidity24))
            
        case 3:
            let coin = liquidityAbove30List[indexPath.row]
            cell.set(coinSymbol: coin.cryptocurrency.name,
                     coinPrice: coin.cryptocurrency.price_usd,
                     change24: coin.cryptocurrency.percent_change_24h,
                     liquidity24: String(format: "%.2f", coin.liquidity24))
            
        default:
            let coin = liquidityBelow10List[indexPath.row]
            cell.set(coinSymbol: coin.cryptocurrency.name,
                     coinPrice: coin.cryptocurrency.price_usd,
                     change24: coin.cryptocurrency.percent_change_24h,
                     liquidity24: String(format: "%.2f", coin.liquidity24))
            
        }
        
        return cell
        
    }    
}
```

Comment: Can you define “when I change the value of `selectedList` in runtime nothing happens”? I assume, of course, that you’re not seeing the UI update. But are you not seeing your `print` statement in the `didSet` of the `selectedList` property of the view model? Perhaps set some breakpoints or add more logging statements to really nail down where the disconnect is in the process. (Truly, with no offense intended, but we shouldn’t have to sift through all this code to see if we can guess where the problem is when a little judicious debugging should really narrow it down.)

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have another view controller where I change the value of the selectedList. The default value when app starts is 0. When I change it to 1 the print statement in the selectedList didSet outputs 1 as expected but the print statement in the didLoadCoins remains 0 thus not triggering any UI changes. I cannot figure out why this is happening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using two different `TVMainViewControllerViewModel` instances. If it was not intended, I guess that might be one of the causes of this issue. This might be the case that you think the view and the view controller are communicating with the same view model instance but not (since there are two).

```
final class TVMainViewControllerView: UIView, TVMainViewControllerViewModelDelegate {
    
    //MARK: - Variables
    private let viewModel: TVMainViewControllerViewModel
    var delegate: TVMainViewControllerViewButtonDelegate?
    
    //MARK: - Initializers
    init(vm: TVMainViewControllerViewModel) {
      super.init(frame: .zero)
      self.viewModel = vm //Allocate view model from initializer.
      self.viewModel.delegate = self
      setupTableView()
      setupUI()
      Task {
            await viewModel.decodeData {
                self.viewModel.delegate?.didLoadCoins()
            }
      }
    }
```

```
class TVMainViewController: UIViewController, TVMainViewControllerViewButtonDelegate {
    
    private let viewModel = TVMainViewControllerViewModel()
    private lazy var mainView = TVMainViewControllerView(vm: self.viewModel)
    
    
    //MARK: - Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
      
        navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
        mainView.delegate = self
       // viewModel.delegate = mainView // This one is not needed.
        setupUI()
        
        
    }
```

I just briefly amended your code to show you what I meant by using only one `TVMainViewControllerViewModel`  instance. Please take a look at what dependency injection is and hope this can give you some clues.